# Android Database

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am creating `ToDoTasks` application in android. i have crated Gui of the application and it is working perfectly. I am able to add `tasks`  in it. Now i want to know that i want to save 'task list' in an area so that every time user comes on it , than it should maintain the list of previous tasks which were added in it. What is the best way to do this ?
Whether i should go for database in android or is there any other way to do this ?

Please suggest me. Please don't mind , i know this is  a silly question but i  have no other way to solve it.....

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options with varying degree of complexity.

Do you foresee sharing your todolist with another application. If yes then you need to host your data as a content provider.But I digress.

The most simplest option is Shared Preferences. The api is very simple to use and you do not need to write a whole lot of plumbing code. You can directly store an list of string in the shared preference of your activity.

The more elaborate solution is using sqllite. If you foresee your domain model to become more complex than just a list of strings, then you should see if the additional complexity is worth it.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for more details. (I will not worry about the file options, the other two mentioned here are superior to that solution)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqlLite db for android. See [this](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954) or [this](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesdatastorage/235-creating-and-using-databases-in-android-one) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example of an SQLite implementation:

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-simple-but-persistent-data-storage/